# How to manage parameter in thick box tb_show function?

Tags: php, thickbox

I am using below script on a form `(say, form-A)` to load another form `(form-B)` in thickbox, with values passed by controller.
First, in `form-A`, i am selecting one option from dropdown "customerID", then "Add Project" button (with id 'addProject') becomes visible, on clicking which, a thickbox appears with form-B in it. Here, in form-B, i want to pass selected customer. How can I do that?
I tried below code, and tried to access the `$_GET['custID']` in controller's `manage_project` function, but it is showing blank. But when i am alerting the url1 (i have commented below), ID is coming there.
Below code is in form-A view file.

```
('#addProject').click(function(){
        var url1='<?php echo SITEURL ?>/xome/invoice/manage_project?TB_iframe=true&height=800&width=700&inlineId=innerDiv&class=thickbox&custID='+$('#customerID').val();

        //alert(url1);
        tb_show('Add More Project',url1,'');
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to documentation at (http://thickbox.net/):

> Important to Remember: Add all other query parameters before the
>   TB_iframe parameters. Everything after the "TB" is removed from the
>   URL.

So, try add custID before TB_iframe. And then you will be able to operate with a variable in the script, such as access them via `$_GET['custID']`.  For example:

```
var url1='<?php echo SITEURL ?>/xome/invoice/manage_project?custID='+$('#customerID').val() + '&TB_iframe=true&height=800&width=700&inlineId=innerDiv&class=thickbox';
```

Comment: Thank you, i searched this answer for a hour